# Using Present Perfect and Perfect Gerund in the same sentence

Tags: present-perfect, gerunds

Is it acceptable to write:

> He has never mentioned having met with you in London.

Or, maybe, it would be better to write:

> He has never mentioned meeting with you in London.

The second variant goes well here as well as the previous one because of the opportunity of using Perfect Gerund instead of Present Gerund. I have the main verb used in the Perfect Form, though. That is the reason of my having posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. Some would find your first example cumbersome, and would prefer your second. There is very little difference in meaning, in practice.

Comment: What do you mean by "cumbersome"? May count on your futher explaining?